# how to show empty rows(datagridtemplatecolumn) into wpf datagrid

Tags: wpf, datagrid, rows

Can any one please help me out to display empty rows into datagrid.
So that I should be able to create a control into datagrid cells dynamically on button click.

Thanks in advance.